# sell music in app

Tags: iphone

I have an app, I hope to sell some music,
Is it possible to become the affiliate for apple music store?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 1):

This might be of interest:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/

You can join that Affiliate program and get provision from sold music from your website *and app*. All information is right there on that site.